# Algorithm for neatly indenting SQL statements (Python implementation would be nice)

Tags: python, sql, coding-style, indentation, pretty-print

I'd like to reformat some SQL statements that are a single string with newlines in to something that's much easier to read.

I don't personally know of a good coding style for indenting SQL - how should nested queries / where clauses / left joins / etc by represented to maximise readability?

Has anyone seen a pretty-printing algorithm that does this already? In Python would be even better.