# Make Emacs less aggressive about indentation

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation, cc-mode

Emacs reindents the current line whenever I type certain things, like ";" or "//".  This is pretty annoying, since there are a whole lot of places where it isn't smart enough to indent correctly.

How do I disable this feature?  I still want to be able to indent the line with TAB, but I don't want any source code I type to cause it to reindent.

(I'm using Dylan Moonfire's C# mode, but this probably applies to any cc-mode.)

Comment: When it works, it's an awesome feature. As you've experienced, it's a ridiculous unbelievably difficult feature to nail down. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318976/smart-indent-algorithm-documentation

Comment: I don't think it's "unbelievably difficult".  csharp-mode.el was last updated in 2007, when C# 2.0 was the latest version.  I think the only hard part is finding an elisp hacker who wants to deal with maintaining a C# mode.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running [c-toggle-electric-state](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Electric-C.html) to turn off the electric action of these characters.

You can do this as part of a c-mode-common-hook, or toggle the state manually by hitting `C-c C-l`.

Answer (score 1):

most likely caused by the `inline-and-indent` ['feature'](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Mode_002dSpecific-Indent.html) of c-mode and derivatives. [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentation) has several solutions.