# Emacs C++ mode indentation

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Emacs less aggressive about indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330066/make-emacs-less-aggressive-about-indentation)

Whenever I type and open or closed parenthesis in Emacs' C++ mode it indents the entire expression. I do not want this to happen. How can I turn this feature off? Can I turn off all auto indent features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `(c-toggle-electric-state -1)`

From the docs:

> c-toggle-electric-state is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `cc-cmds.el'.
>
> (c-toggle-electric-state &optional ARG)
>
> Toggle the electric indentation feature. Optional numeric ARG, if
>   supplied, turns on electric indentation when positive, turns it off
>   when negative, and just toggles it when zero or left out.